# checking for ZLB_Compress in -lzlib... no configure: error: zlib missing

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I got a really big and "old"(form me as a fresh graduate) client-server project. The client is in c++ for Windows and I managed to compile it, but the server is on linux and it is a pain because I don't know that well linux programming. I am trying to make it work in Ubuntu 14.04

I get this error

```
checking for db_new in -ldb_psql... no
configure: error: db_psql missing; install extc
```

So I searched the folders they have provided and foud some files named db_psql in a folder that has a configure.in file. I got with the terminal there and used the command

```
autoreconf -fis
```

which gives me this:

```
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
libtoolize: linking file `./ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `m4'.
libtoolize: linking file `m4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: linking file `m4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: linking file `m4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: linking file `m4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: linking file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
libtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
```

And then I use the command

```
./configure
```

But this gives me two errors saying that other packages are missing, I install them, and then it says that

```
checking for ZLB_Compress in -lzlib... no
configure: error: zlib missing
```

and I am stuck here. Nothing seems to work. I even searched "zlib" in Ubuntu Software Center and installed everything in there(I installed zlib1g-dev and many others). I used  --with-zlib-dir=/usr

I have this code in configure.in

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([zlib], [ZLB_Compress],

[AMADEUS_LIBS="-lzlib $AMADEUS_LIBS"],

[AC_MSG_ERROR([zlib missing])])
```

and this one in configure

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
char ZLB_Compress ();
int
main ()
{
return ZLB_Compress ();
  ;
  return 0;
}
_ACEOF
if ac_fn_c_try_link "$LINENO"; then :
  ac_cv_lib_zlib_ZLB_Compress=yes
else
  ac_cv_lib_zlib_ZLB_Compress=no
fi
rm -f core conftest.err conftest.$ac_objext \
    conftest$ac_exeext conftest.$ac_ext
LIBS=$ac_check_lib_save_LIBS
fi
{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: $ac_cv_lib_zlib_ZLB_Compress" >&5
$as_echo "$ac_cv_lib_zlib_ZLB_Compress" >&6; }
if test "x$ac_cv_lib_zlib_ZLB_Compress" = xyes; then :
  AMADEUS_LIBS="-lzlib $AMADEUS_LIBS"
else
  as_fn_error $? "zlib missing" "$LINENO" 5
fi
```

Comment: Not sure what all that `autotools` stuff has to do with the title of the question, in which you never really asked a specific question, but you should probably at least note that, while the software project and package are generally referred to as ZLib or zlib, the library it produces is generally called `libz.so` (or `libz.a`) and is linked via just `-lz` (because the linker provides the "lib" prefix...

Comment: I was just telling what I did to make it easier for you guys to understand what mith be the problem. My question is what is wrong with the code. As I have said I never programmed in linux before. They gave me this this project to see if it can be compiled, if it can it would be great, if not it is not such a big problem. There is no one who knows linux in the company.